# Control 'base' point size in ggplot aes(size)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to increase or decrease the all the points in the graph below with a factor. I can control the within the aes. And I can control the size outside aes. But I can't figure out how to combine both.

```
df <- data.frame(val1 = rnorm(10, 5), val2 = rnorm(10, 5), size = rnorm(10, 5))
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(val1, val2, size = size))
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can change the base sizes using the `scale_size_` function. For example,

```
g = ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(val1, val2, size = size))
g + scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 6))
g + scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 18))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the answer I was hoping for.